# Add different labels to show totals in stacked bar plot in ggplot R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, label, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

My question is somewhat similar to this:
[How to add text label to show total n in each bar of stacked proportion bars in ggplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65201095/how-to-add-text-label-to-show-total-n-in-each-bar-of-stacked-proportion-bars-in)

However, the solutions offered there don't work in my case because the stacked bars are not always the same height and don't add up to 100%

I will let the example speak for itself:

```
company=c('CompanyA','CompanyA', 'CompanyA', 'CompanyA','CompanyB', 'CompanyB', 'CompanyB', 'CompanyB')
SubSegment = c('SubSeg1', 'SubSeg1', 'SubSeg2', 'SubSeg2', 'SubSeg1', 'SubSeg1', 'SubSeg2', 'SubSeg2')
variable = c('Ratio1', 'Ratio2','Ratio1', 'Ratio2','Ratio1', 'Ratio2','Ratio1', 'Ratio2')
value = c(0.311, 0.256, 0.389, 0.105, 0.256, 0.1002, 0.2569, 0.2856)
df = as.data.frame(cbind(company, SubSegment, variable, value))
df=df%>% mutate(Label=value)
df[,4:ncol(df)]<- sapply(df[,4:ncol(df)] , as.numeric)
df[,ncol(df)]<- sapply(df[,ncol(df)] , function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.1))

var_levels= c('Ratio1', 'Ratio2')
colors= c("#F3DF6C", "cyan")

plot.1<- ggplot(df, aes(fill=factor(variable, levels = var_levels), y=value, x=company)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", alpha=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.6)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=2.5) +
  #geom_text(data=df_totals_2, aes(x= Company, label= Label, y=value, fill=NULL), nudge_y=10)+
  facet_wrap(~factor(SubSegment ), ncol=1)  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),     panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.88, 0.89) , legend.text = element_text(size = 9.5),
        legend.title =  element_text(size = 11),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray92", linetype="solid",colour ="gray75")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors, name="SubSegment") + 
  coord_flip()

plot(plot.1)
```

By doing that I get the following plot:
[image: Stacked Plot with labels inside]

I would like to also add a label that will give the total of each stacked bar:

```
df_t = df[,c(1,2,4)] # df with TOTALS
df_t[,ncol(df_t)]<- sapply(df_t[,ncol(df_t)] , as.numeric)
df_t = df_t %>% group_by(company, SubSegment) %>%
  summarise(value = sum(value)) %>% mutate(Label=value)
df_t[,ncol(df_t)]<- sapply(df_t[,ncol(df_t)] , function(x) scales::percent(x, accuracy = 0.1))
```

If I plotted the totals without the stacked plot I could get something like this:
[image]

Basically, I want to "combine" the two plots, or simply add the total labels to the stacked plot.
I have tried a few different approaches but I can't get the totals to appear on the right place (at the end of each bar)

for the non-stacked barplot this is what I used to create the labels:

```
plot.2<- ggplot(df_t, aes(fill=company, y=value, x=company)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = 'dodge')+
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.6)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Label),position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.25, hjust=-0.2) +
 facet_wrap(~factor(SubSegment ), ncol=1)  + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your second dataframe `df_t` in a new `geom_text` where you could add for example 0.03 to `value` by specifing the position of your labels. You can use the following code:

```
library(ggplot2)
plot.1<- ggplot(df, aes(fill=factor(variable, levels = var_levels), y=value, x=company)) + 
  geom_bar(position="stack", stat="identity", alpha=1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.6)) +
  geom_text(aes(label=Label), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size=2.5) +
  geom_text(aes(company, value + 0.03, label = Label, fill = NULL), data = df_t) +
  facet_wrap(~factor(SubSegment ), ncol=1)  +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 11), axis.title.x = element_blank(), axis.title.y = element_blank(), axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank(),     panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        legend.position = c(0.88, 0.89) , legend.text = element_text(size = 9.5),
        legend.title =  element_text(size = 11),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray92", linetype="solid",colour ="gray75")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values=colors, name="SubSegment") + 
  coord_flip()

plot(plot.1)
```

Output:

[image]